# Android. Не вмещается текст в одну строку на разных устройствах

Tags: android, android-layout

Проблема такова. Имеется Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Кнопка_1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Кнопка_2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Кнопка_3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Если кратко - три кнопки в ряд по горизонтали. На некоторых устройствах текст кнопки не вмещается и переносится. Можно как вариант уменьшить размер текста, но это портит ui на устройствах с большим экраном и разрешением - слишком мелко.

Другой вариант - android:autoSizeTextType. Но проблема в этом случае в том, что короткий текст не уменьшится, а длинный на соседней кнопке - уменьшится. Что для кнопок в ряд, опять же, не подходит.

Зацепиться за какие-то параметры экрана? Вот два экрана:

6.26"
DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=720, height=1369, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=281.353, ydpi=279.768}

6.2"
DisplayMetrics{density=1.75, width=720, height=1382, scaledDensity=1.75, xdpi=268.941, ydpi=269.986}

На первом текстовки не помещаются, на втором - помещаются. В какую сторону "копать"? За что зацепиться?

Comment: я вам больше скажу, нужно еще учитывать предпочтения пользователя, он может установить в настройках телефона размер шрифта ExtraLarge

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос. Попробуйте покопать в сторону программного определения размеров вьюхи до отрисовки. Из этого, по идее, можно будет вычислить есть ли перенос строк в одной из них и уменьшать его, заново измеряя, пока оно не поместится.